# How to run AIR desktop app on Android (Galaxy Tab 10.1)?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, galaxy-tab

I have a problem - How to run AIR (really big desktop application) on my Galaxy Tab 10.1?
It's possible convert .air to .apk?

EDIT:

1. I set up a new desktop project (File -> New -> Flex Project)
2. Project name is "simpleTest", Application type is Desktop (runs in Adobe AIR), Flex SDK version 4.6.0 and click to Finish
3. I go to Design mode, then set the width to 500 and height to 250. I add one button by drawing and name it btnOne and make Generate Event Handler

4.Then I go to Project -> Export Release Build (Export as Signed AIR package) -> Next (I apply the certificate) -> Finish

5. I find the project file (...Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\simpleTest) and copy simpleTest.air into a new file (simpleTestAPK - which contains my certificate > andCert.p12)

6. I rename "simpleTest.air" to "simpleTest.zip" and from this .zip I unpack just "simpleTest.swf" and "application.xml"

7. I create a "create.txt" containing as follows:

adt -package -target apk-debug -storetype pkcs12 -keystore andCert.p12
myHope.apk application.xml simpleTest.swf

8. I rename "create.txt" to "create.cmd" and launch it (Shift + RMB -> Open cmd here)

9. "myHope.apk" is created

10. I copy this to Galaxy Tab 10.1 (with drag&drop)

11. I launch "myHope.apk" but all I see is blank, white screen, no colors, no buttons, nothing.


Any ideas, recommendations, suggestions? Thaks.

Comment: You can (see answers below), but remember, the air framework for mobile apps is a reduced version of the desktop framework, so some components may not work.

Comment: In test project "simpleTest" I use only Spark components.

Comment: If you have Flash Builder then you can build directly from FB. make it a Flex Mobile project

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with such a simple project as "simpleTest" for it's using just Spark components. But it is a problem with my big desktop application because I'm using mx components in there (and rewriting them would take a very long time). 
It would be optimal to launch an .air application on the tablet without rewriting anything...
(I'm ready to rewrite some tens of code lines, but few hundreds is already a bit more comlicated)

Comment: Don't think THAT's possible. you will have to rewrite the app for a mobile project, though you should be able to reuse most of your code. Create a mobile project, copy all your desktop code into it, and then correct the errors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. As commonly know .air file is actually a zip archive, so you can just change extension of file from .air to .zip and unpack its content. You'll need to take <your_app>-app.xml and <your_app>.swf files from the unpacked archive. Then go to the bin folder of flex sdk with adobe air 2.7 and higher in it.

Then launch console and execute the following code:

```
adt -package -target apk-debug -storetype pkcs12 -keystore <your_certificate>.p12 <your_app_name>.apk <your_app_name>-app.xml <your_app_name>.swf
```

More detailed description is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html).

Update [12.12.2011]:
To get **desktop** .air working on the mobile device a little trick should be done - change the `WindowedApplication` to the `Application` component and make a release build. After that you'll do the steps as described above and it should work. This works for mx-based components, haven't tried with spark, but I guess it also should work.

Comment: I have installed AIR runtime, create .apk (with adt).
Ok, .apk created.
But, if I click to my app icon, app freeze in flash loading screen. I use FB 4.6

Comment: @DominikRT does this happen in the emulator or on the device or both?

Comment: On device. Not tested on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have android sdk and now you can install all .apk from disk drive to your mobile device

adb -s XXXX9999XXXX install -r yourfile.apk

XXXX9999XXXX - device serial number

and for debugging width flash builder:
you need to have SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones to see Galaxy Tab in Flash builder

http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/what-to-do-when-flash-builder-4-5-doesn-t-see-your-android-device

cheers

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to download the AIR runtime from the Market. Then you should be able to run the .air file.

You can find it here: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.air&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hZG9iZS5haXIiXQ..